# High CPU usage by Apache in XAMPP and Laragon

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, httpd.conf, laragon

I'm running Windows 10 and I've been suffering from slowness in my XAMPP and now my Laragon. I tried virtually all the tips and tricks available online to speed them up, but none worked. It takes me like 8 seconds just to load my WordPress admin dashboard. The more I run them, the slower it gets.

Here's my netstat output below. Not sure why there're so many 5XXXX ports running.
[image]

And here's my Apache showing HIGH CPU usage.
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling XDEBUG From PHP.ini helps a lot to try.

Comment: Yes this helped on mine as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is old now, so hopefully you were able to resolve it. Two things I noticed... extremely high memory usage as well, and several remote IP addresses active.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps someone, I was using wrong version of XDEBUG. As soon as I replaced it with the correct version, it started running smoothly again.

You can use [XDebug Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard) and paste your `phpinfo()` output into it to figure out which exact version of the DLL you need.